# Open cv is not reading image

Tags: c++, opencv, path, imread

Here is my piece of code. But every time it shows data cannot be read. I have tried multiple formates of writing path to image but that did not worked. Any one else facing same problem?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include <vector>
using namespace cv;
int main()
{
    Mat source = imread("C:\\Untitled.jpg");
    namedWindow("My Image");
    waitKey(0);
    if (!source.data)
    {
         std::cout << "Data cannot be read" << std::endl;
         return -1;
    }
    imshow("My Image", source);
    destroyAllWindows();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Does `imread` return any sort of error code? Is it possible that you need double escaping (i.e. `\\\\` instead of `\\`)?

Comment: I had a similar issue. Try `imread(cv::String("C:\\Untitled.jpg"))`. Don't know why it worked. The other option is that you lack an external dll necessary to open jpeg image.

Comment: Check the directory and image exist and also check the format in windows for reading. You can reach directory by properties of image . Also what does that `waitKey` doing in there

Comment: @ALX23z it worked for me too. Thanks alot. There was close to zero progress from last two days in my project. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

`imshow()` must be followed by `waitKey()` or you can never see the named window.

```
imshow("My Image", source);
waitKey(0);  // should be here.
destroyAllWindows();
```

The note for `imshow()` in OpenCV 2.4 says:

> This function should be followed by waitKey function which displays the image for specified milliseconds. Otherwise, it won’t display the image. ...